# How high and wide will NSString write?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quartz-graphics

How do I work out how much large an area drawing an NSString will occupy, i.e. by using:

```
[string drawAtPoint:p withAttributes:nil];
```

I ideally need to work this out before its drawn so I can space out the "areas" in which the strings are drawn appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`-[NSString sizeWithAttributes:]`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes:) message.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`. It's an addition to `NSString` provided by `UIKit` (look for "NSString UIKit Additions Reference" in the docs).

Comment: This stuff can be so hard to find in the documentation. This only works for iPhone not for desktop cocoa.

Comment: I assumed you were looking for an iPhone solution since the question is tagged as cocoa-touch. I'll remove that tag.

Comment: Actually i tagged it with cocoa and cocoa-touch because I am writing an app for both cocoa and cocoa-touch. (: